# KnockoutJS - ViewModel Grandparent - Parent - Child using ko.computed to access Parent/Grandparent Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a Grandparent, Parent, Child ViewModel relationship setup in knockout and knockout mapping,  CustomerViewModel, WorkOrderViewModel, and RepairViewModel.

I want to setup a child ko.computed value within the child that Take the amount of hours in the RepairViewModel and multiplies it by Rate within the WorkOrderView Model.

Within the RepairViewModel I have code like this:

```
self.RepairCost = ko.computed(function () {

             return (self.Hours() * self.parent.LabourChargeCost()).toFixed(2);
     });
```

Is there any way to get the parent's value?

Thanks so much!

Here is the JS code I'm using (simplified):

```
var workOrderMapping = {
    'WorkOrders': {
        key: function (workOrders) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(workOrders.WorkOrderId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new WorkOrderViewModel(options.data);
        }
    },

    'Repairs': {
        key: function (repairs) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(repairs.RepairId);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return new RepairViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};


RepairViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, workOrderMapping, self);

     self.RepairCost = ko.computed(function () {    
         return (self.Hours() * self.parent.LabourChargeCost()).toFixed(2);
     })

    ;
}

WorkOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, workOrderMapping, self);

}

CustomerViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, workOrderMapping, self);

    self.save = function () {
        //alert(ko.toJSON(self));
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Customers/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("succ");
                //alert(data.customerViewModel);
                // if (data.customerViewModel != null) {
                //alert("succ2");
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Saved',
                    text: 'Record saved successfully',
                    type: 'success',
                    styling: 'bootstrap3'

                });


                ko.mapping.fromJS(data.customerViewModel, workOrderMapping, self);

                if (data.newLocation != null)
                    window.location = data.newLocation;
            },


        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the parent in the child model unless you pass the parent to the child and kept a reference.

What has worked better for me in the past is passing the value to the child model and then add to subscribe in the parent to update the child when the value is changed.

```
function Parent(){
  var self = this;
  self.someValue = ko.obserable();//init if you need to
  self.children = [new Child(self.someValue())]

  self.someValue.subscribe(function(value){
      for(var i = 0;i<self.children.length;i++){
          self.children[i].parentValue(value);
      }
  });
}
function Child(value){
    var self = this;
    self.parentValue = ko.observable(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do that, and it is a limitation not of Knockout but JS: you don't have access to the parent context from within an object property. 
What you can do is, as @GrayTower mentioned, pass your parent as a parameter, but this to me, feels a bit like a hack (I admit to using it sometimes though). 
You could also modify your child viewmodels once they have been initiated, from either within the parent, or externally, before the view model is bound. I don't really understand the flow of properties in the code you presented, but I hope a smaller test case will suit your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/507k237y/. Suppose we have the following parent-child viewmodels:

```
// symbolizes an employee
function ChildVM(name, hoursWorked) {
    var self = this, parent;
    this.name = name;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}
// symbolizes a payment system
function MasterVM() {
    var self = this;
    this.rate = 25; // dollars/hour
    this.employees = [
        new ChildVM('Chris',16),
        new ChildVM('Cagle',32)
    ];
}
var app = new MasterVM(), 
    view = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

We want to add a property `payout` to each `ChildVM` in `employees`, which will use `rate` from `MasterVM` in combination with `hoursWorked` from `ChildVM`, i.e. a `ko.computed`. You could simply paste a function inside the `MasterVM` constructor, like this:

```
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.employees, function(i) {
      i.payout = ko.computed(function() {
          return i.hoursWorked*self.rate;
      });
  });
```

Or you could make it a method and call it before calling `ko.applyBindings`:

```
    this.initEmployees = function() {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.employees, function(i) {
            i.payout = ko.computed(function() {
                return i.hoursWorked*self.rate;
            });
        });
    }
    app.initEmployees();
    ko.applyBindings(app, view);
```

Or you could even build an `applyBindings` wrapper, which executes a 'callBefore' (cf. <=> AJAX `callbacks`) before binding the view and the model, like so:

```
function initVM(VM, callbefore, element) {
    callbefore(VM);
    ko.applyBindings(VM, element);
}
initVM(app, function(vm) {
   ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.employees, function(i) {
     i.payout = ko.computed(function() {
        return i.hoursWorked*vm.rate;
     });
   });
},view);
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/507k237y/)**
**Note:** Using `ko.mapping.fromJS`converts **all** values to observables, while when your values don't need updating you don't need observables, you can use plain JS values/ objects.